# Eigen, rotate a vector3d with a quaternion?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an array of  3D points, as an `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>`.

I need to transform these points with a position and quaternion.

My questions are:

How can I rotate these points with a quaternion? And is there a faster way than:

```
    Eigen::Vector3d Trans; // position to move by
    Eigen::Quaterniond quats;  // quat to rotate by

for (int p = 0; p < objectPoints.size(); p++)
        {
            Eigen::Vector3d pnt;
            //add pose
            pnt.x = objectPointsTri[p].x + -Trans.x();
            pnt.y = objectPointsTri[p].y + -Trans.y();
            pnt.z = objectPointsTri[p].z + -Trans.z();

            Eigen::Vector3d pntRot = // rotate pnt by the quaternion



        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Operator `*` will do the job, and you can of course simplify your code:

```
pnt = objectPointsTri[p] - Trans;
pntRot = quat * pnt;
```

or even:

```
pnt = quat * (objectPointsTri[p] - Trans);
```

or, if you store your points in a `Matrix3Xd`:

```
Matrix3Xd in_pts;
Matrix3Xd out_pts;
Affine3d T = quats * Translation3d(-Trans);
out_pts = T * in_pts;
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer from @ggael is perfectly correct, I'd just like to provide some background.

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation&oldid=857554758#Using_quaternion_as_rotations) they explain quaternion-vector multiplication v’ = qvq<sup>-1</sup>. The Eigen shorthand with `operator*` we're using is also apparently in [Unity libraries](https://answers.unity.com/questions/372371/multiply-quaternion-by-vector3-how-is-done.html).

In the current version of Eigen, you'd be selecting [this overload](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1RotationBase.html#a09a4757e7aff7a95bebf4fa8a965a4eb) of `operator*`, which calls `_transformVector`

```
template<typename RotationDerived,typename OtherVectorType>
struct rotation_base_generic_product_selector<RotationDerived,OtherVectorType,true>
{
  ...
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC static EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE ReturnType run(const RotationDerived& r, const OtherVectorType& v)
  {
    return r._transformVector(v);
  }
};
```

See the **Remarks** on `_transformVector` [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1QuaternionBase.html#aabef1f6fc62535f6f85d590108915ee8):

> If the quaternion is used to rotate several points (>1) then it is much more efficient to first convert it to a 3x3 Matrix. Comparison of the operation cost for n transformations:
>
> - Quaternion2: 30n
> - Via a Matrix3: 24 + 15n

ggael asked you to change how you solve the problem for these efficiency reasons.