# Rotate a std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> as a rigid transformation?

Tags: c++, eigen, point-clouds

I have a few 3d points, stored in a `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>`. I need to rigidly rotate and translate these points, without changing their relationship to one another. As if moving the cloud as a whole.

Based on this question:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507665/eigen-rotate-a-vector3d-with-a-quaternion`

I have this code:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> pts, ptsMoved;


Eigen::Quaterniond rotateBy = Eigen::Quaterniond(0.1,0.5,0.08,0.02);
Eigen::Vector3d translateBy(1, 2.5, 1.5);


for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); i++)
{
    //transform point                   
    Vector3d rot = rotateBy * (pts[i] + translateBy);
    ptsMoved.push_back(rot);

}
```

When i view the points and compare them to the original points, however, I get this: (White are the original, green are the transformed).

[image: points]

What i expect, is the cloud as a whole to look the same, just in a different position and orientation. What i get, is a moved and rotated and scaled cloud, that looks different to the original. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

If i apply the inverse transform to the adjusted points, using:

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> pntsBack;
for (int i = 0; i < ptsMoved.size(); i++)
{
    //transform point       
    Vector3d rot = rotateBy.inverse() * (ptsMoved[i] - translateBy);
    pntsBack.push_back(rot);
}
```

It gives me an even worse result. (dark green = original points, white = transformed, light green = transformed inverse)

[image]

Comment: If you apply the inverse transform to the transformed points, do you get back to where you started?

Comment: Or even better, apply the inverse transform to the camera, and compare *those* pictures

Comment: thanks for your reply. using `Vector3d rot = rotateBy.inverse() * (ptsMoved[i] -translateBy);` to apply the inverse, I get a very incorrect result.

Comment: that isn't the opposite transformation. Iirc it would be `(rotateBy.inverse() * ptsMoved[i]) - translateBy;`

Comment: To me, the differences look like [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax)

Comment: I just made that change :) Still very wrong result, however. I am attaching the result as image to question..

Comment: Apparently, according to your link, it is possible to get the equivalent 3x3 rotation matrix. You could print it, and/or check it is an unitary matrix

Comment: You can also apply rotation + inverse to vectors (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1)

Comment: You could show us the code you used to calculate the quaternion

Comment: hi, the quaternion is random, to test the transform

Comment: Is it normalized ? What is its norm ?

Comment: as above, `Eigen::Quaterniond(0.1,0.5,0.08,0.02);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Quaternion is not a unit-Quaternion, therefore you will get unspecified results.
If you are not sure your quaternion is normalized, just write

```
rotateBy.normalize();
```

before using it. Additionally, if you want to rotate more than one vector it is more efficient to convert the Quaternion to a rotation matrix:

```
Eigen::Matrix3d rotMat = rotateBy.toRotationMatrix();
// ...
// inside for loop:
    Vector3d rot = rotMat * (ptsMoved[i] - translateBy);
```

Also, instead of `.inverse()` you can use `.conjugate()` for unit quaternions and `.adjoint()` or `.transpose()` for orthogonal Matrices.

Comment: Thank you! This has indeed fixed my issue. However, when I try to get the points back to where they started, using `Vector3d rot = rotateBy.conjugate() * (ptsMoved[i] - translateBy);` The rotation looks correct, but the translation is off in one axis.

Comment: Adjusting teh order of operations has fixed this last part. `Vector3d rot = rotateBy.conjugate() * (ptsMoved[i]);
  rot = rot - translateBy;` thank you again for your help!